# Default context menu for RichTextEdit?

Tags: c#, winforms

There doesn't seem to be a default context menu (with copy, paste, etc.) for the RichTextEdit control in WinForms? I try right-clicking inside the RichTextEdit and nothing happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The RTE control doesn't have a default context menu. But you can assign it your own.